# Unlist data frame column preserving information from other column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame which consists of two column: a character vector `col1` and a `list` column, `col2`.

```
myVector <- c("A","B","C","D")

myList <- list()
myList[[1]] <- c(1, 4, 6, 7)
myList[[2]] <- c(2, 7, 3)
myList[[3]] <- c(5, 5, 3, 9, 6)
myList[[4]] <- c(7, 9)

myDataFrame <- data.frame(row = c(1,2,3,4))

myDataFrame$col1 <- myVector
myDataFrame$col2 <- myList

myDataFrame
# row col1          col2
# 1   1    A    1, 4, 6, 7
# 2   2    B       2, 7, 3
# 3   3    C 5, 5, 3, 9, 6
# 4   4    D          7, 9
```

I want to unlist my `col2` still keeping for each element of the vectors in the list the information stored in `col1`. To phrase it differently, in commonly used data frame reshape terminology: the "wide" list column should be converted to a "long" format.

Then at the end of the day I want two vectors of length equal to `length(unlist(myDataFrame$col2))`. In code:

```
# unlist myList
unlist.col2 <- unlist(myDataFrame$col2)
unlist.col2
# [1] 1 4 6 7 2 7 3 5 5 3 9 6 7 9

# unlist myVector to obtain
# unlist.col1 <- ???
# unlist.col1
# [1] A A A A B B B C C C C C D D
```

I can't think of any straightforward way to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, the idea is to first get the length of each list element using `sapply` and then use `rep` to replicate the `col1` with that `length`

```
 l1 <- sapply(myDataFrame$col2, length)
  unlist.col1 <- rep(myDataFrame$col1, l1)
  unlist.col1
 #[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D"
```

Or as suggested by @Ananda Mahto, the above could be also done with `vapply`

```
   with(myDataFrame, rep(col1, vapply(col2, length, 1L)))
  #[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D"
```

Answer (score 37):

You may also use `unnest` from package `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(myDataFrame, col2)

#      row  col1  col2
#    (dbl) (chr) (dbl)
# 1      1     A     1
# 2      1     A     4
# 3      1     A     6
# 4      1     A     7
# 5      2     B     2
# 6      2     B     7
# 7      2     B     3
# 8      3     C     5
# 9      3     C     5
# 10     3     C     3
# 11     3     C     9
# 12     3     C     6
# 13     4     D     7
# 14     4     D     9
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "data.table" to expand the whole `data.frame`, and extract the column of interest.

```
library(data.table)
## expand the entire data.frame (uncomment to see)
# as.data.table(myDataFrame)[, unlist(col2), by = list(row, col1)]

## expand and select the column of interest:
as.data.table(myDataFrame)[, unlist(col2), by = list(row, col1)]$col1
#  [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D"
```

---

In newer versions of R, you can now use the `lengths` function instead of the `sapply(list, length)` approach. The `lengths` function is considerably faster.

```
with(myDataFrame, rep(col1, lengths(col2)))
#  [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D"
```