# Expand list column of data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with a list column, where each element is a `data.table`:

```
dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 1, 2),
                 var = list(data.table(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4)),
                            data.table(a = c(5, 6), b = c(7, 8)),
                            data.table(a = 9, b = 10)))

dt
# id             var
# 1:  1 <data.table>
# 2:  1 <data.table>
# 3:  2 <data.table>
```

Now I want to "unlist" this structure to:

```
   a  b id
1: 1  3  1
2: 2  4  1
3: 5  7  1
4: 6  8  1
5: 9 10  2
```

I know how to expand the embedded `data.table` part with `rbindlist`, but just have no idea how to bind the flattened `data.table` with variable "id".

The original dataset is 30 million lines and with dozens of variables, so I would really appreciate if you would propose solution not only workable but also memory efficient.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for your comment but I have to say this solution only works for situation where id is unique. If the id is duplicated then var[[1]] only retrieve the first row of each id. I've modified my example to incorporate this situation.

Comment: Ok, my answer (below) already handles that, I guess.

Comment: Related: [Unlist data frame column preserving information from other column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194298/unlist-data-frame-column-preserving-information-from-other-column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case `dt[, var[[1]], by=id]` works. However, I use `rbindlist` as the OP mentioned:

```
dt[, r := as.character(.I) ]
res <- dt[, rbindlist(setNames(var, r), id="r")]
```

Then merge on `r` (rows of `dt`) if you really need any vars from there:

```
res[dt, on=.(r), `:=`(id = i.id)]
```

This is better than `dt[, var[[1]], by=id]` in a few ways:

- `rbindlist` should be faster than something with a lot of `by=` groups.
- If there are more vars in `dt`, all of them will have to end up in `by=`.
- Probably, it is not necessary to carry over vars from `dt` at all, since they can always be grabbed from that table later and they take up a lot less memory there.

Comment: Fwiw, here's an illustration of what I have in mind regarding "more vars" in `dt`: http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#rbindlist-read (the `fn` and `year` columns)

Comment: Thanks! I'm digging into it.

Comment: Your code saved my life! It's super fast. Now I only got one question that I didn't see it necessary to add the "setNames" function in the rbindlist since I get the same result without it. Could you explain it?

Comment: @R.Zhu Cool! Yes, good observation, you are right. I guess I habitually use it, since in general, one might want the linking column to be something other than the row numbers. For example, if `dt[, r := sprintf("%07f.", .I)]` (row numbers with leading zeros) or if handling files (like the linked example) and using file names to link.

Comment: @Frank Excellent R/data.table tutorial! Thanks for sharing.