# Expand multiple columns of data.table containing <list> observations

Tags: r, data.table, rbindlist

I have a `data.table` where more than 2 columns are of the type `list`. I would like to expand these columns, so that each element of the list becomes a new column. I would like to have a more elegant way than to "manually" expand each column and then join the tables together.

**the setup**

**Edit:** (providing the `json` from which i obtained the `data.table`)

So i have a `json` file like this:

```
[
    {
        "origins": [
            {
                "orig_lon": "14.36784",
                "orig_lat": "49.985982",
                "local_id": "AD.22045279",
                "full_address": "Věštínská 36/9, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5"
            },
            {
                "orig_lon": "14.352792",
                "orig_lat": "49.983317",
                "local_id": "AD.22055428",
                "full_address": "Otínská 1102/37, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5"
            }
        ],
        "destinations": [
            {
                "dest_lon": "14.352245",
                "dest_lat": "49.981314",
                "local_id": "AD.22045848",
                "full_address": "Zderazská 98/3, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5"
            },
            {
                "dest_lon": "14.226975",
                "dest_lat": "50.051702",
                "local_id": "AD.27261433",
                "full_address": "Západní 458, 25303 Chýně"
            }
        ],
        "destination_addresses": [
            "Zderazská 98/3, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia",
            "Západní 458, 253 01 Chýně, Czechia"
        ],
        "origin_addresses": [
            "U Jankovky 455/18, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia",
            "Otínská 1102/37, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia"
        ],
        "rows": [
            {
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "1.6 km",
                            "value": 1620
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "5 mins",
                            "value": 272
                        },
                        "duration_in_traffic": {
                            "text": "5 mins",
                            "value": 277
                        },
                        "status": "OK"
                    },
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "19.3 km",
                            "value": 19313
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "22 mins",
                            "value": 1343
                        },
                        "duration_in_traffic": {
                            "text": "24 mins",
                            "value": 1424
                        },
                        "status": "OK"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "0.7 km",
                            "value": 691
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "2 mins",
                            "value": 101
                        },
                        "duration_in_traffic": {
                            "text": "2 mins",
                            "value": 99
                        },
                        "status": "OK"
                    },
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "18.7 km",
                            "value": 18655
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "21 mins",
                            "value": 1246
                        },
                        "duration_in_traffic": {
                            "text": "22 mins",
                            "value": 1336
                        },
                        "status": "OK"
                    }
                ]
            }               
        ],
        "status": "OK"
    },
    {
        "origins": [
            {
                "orig_lon": "14.36784",
                "orig_lat": "49.985982",
                "local_id": "AD.22045279",
                "full_address": "Věštínská 36/9, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5"
            },
            {
                "orig_lon": "14.352792",
                "orig_lat": "49.983317",
                "local_id": "AD.22055428",
                "full_address": "Otínská 1102/37, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5"
            }
        ],
        "destinations": [
            {
                "dest_lon": "14.36053",
                "dest_lat": "49.981687",
                "local_id": "AD.22047131",
                "full_address": "Zítkova 235/7, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5"
            },
            {
                "dest_lon": "14.361052",
                "dest_lat": "49.988529",
                "local_id": "AD.22054952",
                "full_address": "Strážovská 1053/33, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5"
            }
        ],
        "destination_addresses": [
            "Zítkova 235/7, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia",
            "Strážovská 1053/33, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia"
        ],
        "origin_addresses": [
            "U Jankovky 455/18, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia",
            "Otínská 1102/37, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia"
        ],
        "rows": [
            {
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "1.4 km",
                            "value": 1445
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "4 mins",
                            "value": 248
                        },
                        "duration_in_traffic": {
                            "text": "4 mins",
                            "value": 247
                        },
                        "status": "OK"
                    },
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "1.9 km",
                            "value": 1933
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "4 mins",
                            "value": 264
                        },
                        "duration_in_traffic": {
                            "text": "4 mins",
                            "value": 267
                        },
                        "status": "OK"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "1.4 km",
                            "value": 1374
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "4 mins",
                            "value": 232
                        },
                        "duration_in_traffic": {
                            "text": "4 mins",
                            "value": 241
                        },
                        "status": "OK"
                    },
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "1.3 km",
                            "value": 1274
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "3 mins",
                            "value": 167
                        },
                        "duration_in_traffic": {
                            "text": "3 mins",
                            "value": 174
                        },
                        "status": "OK"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "status": "OK"
    }
]
```

Which I read in like:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
data <- read_json('./path_to_that_json/that_json.json')
```

This results in a `list` of length 2.

I can covert this into `data.table` like:

```
dt <- rbindlist(lapply(data, as.data.table))
```

Which then results in a `data.table` like:

```
   origins destinations                             destination_addresses                                 origin_addresses
1:  <list>       <list>     Zderazská 98/3, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia U Jankovky 455/18, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia
2:  <list>       <list>                Západní 458, 253 01 Chýne, Czechia   Otínská 1102/37, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia
3:  <list>       <list>      Zítkova 235/7, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia U Jankovky 455/18, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia
4:  <list>       <list> Strážovská 1053/33, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia   Otínská 1102/37, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia
     rows status
1: <list>     OK
2: <list>     OK
3: <list>     OK
4: <list>     OK
```

This means I have several columns containing list and i would like to expand them.

**what kinda works**

I know that to expand just one column, I can do:

```
dt[, r = as.character(.I)]
res1 <- dt[, rbindlist(setNames(origins, r), id = "r")]
```

(I found that here: [Expand list column of data.tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152845/expand-list-column-of-data-tables) )

Now, i could expand multiple columns by repeating this call and joining the results using the column `r`. This could look like:

```
res1 <- dt[dt[, rbindlist(origins, id = "r")][
  , `:=`(r=as.character(r))], on = "r"][, `:=`(origins = NULL, destinations = NULL)][dt[
    , rbindlist(destinations, id = "r")][
      , `:=`(r=as.character(r))], on = "r"]
```

Which would give me the desired output of:

```
                               destination_addresses                                 origin_addresses   rows status r
1:     Zderazská 98/3, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia U Jankovky 455/18, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia <list>     OK 1
2:                Západní 458, 253 01 Chýne, Czechia   Otínská 1102/37, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia <list>     OK 2
3:      Zítkova 235/7, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia U Jankovky 455/18, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia <list>     OK 3
4: Strážovská 1053/33, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia   Otínská 1102/37, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia <list>     OK 4
    orig_lon  orig_lat    local_id                            full_address  dest_lon  dest_lat  i.local_id
1:  14.36784 49.985982 AD.22045279  Veštínská 36/9, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5 14.352245 49.981314 AD.22045848
2: 14.352792 49.983317 AD.22055428 Otínská 1102/37, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5 14.226975 50.051702 AD.27261433
3:  14.36784 49.985982 AD.22045279  Veštínská 36/9, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5  14.36053 49.981687 AD.22047131
4: 14.352792 49.983317 AD.22055428 Otínská 1102/37, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5 14.361052 49.988529 AD.22054952
                               i.full_address
1:     Zderazská 98/3, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5
2:                   Západní 458, 25303 Chýne
3:      Zítkova 235/7, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5
4: Strážovská 1053/33, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5
```

**My question is:**

Is there a more elegant and more efficient way of expanding several columns? In theory, i would like to have a list of columns to be expanded and then make one call which would expand all of them and return the above result.

Also, with the column `rows`, the expanding is a bit more complicated: so far i am creating a new column of type `list`, which does not include the `status` record. Something like:

```
dt[, rows2 := lapply(rows, function(x) list("distance" = (x[[1]][[1]]["distance"]),
                                         "duration" = (x[[1]][[1]]["duration"]),
                                         "duration_in_traffic" = (x[[1]][[1]]["duration_in_traffic"])))]
```

And then the above procedure can be used to expand `rows2` into three columns of type `list`, which can be subsequently expanded using the same procedure. Now, this approach sucks for the obvious reason as not being really straightforward for anyone who reads the code after me. Moreover, it takes a lot of typing. I think there must be way more elegant way of wrangling this.

Comment: Oh, in case anyone notices that the: `destination_addresses` and `origin_addresses `columns do not match exactly the `full_address` columns, that is not a problem in my data set: it's just that `google` api sometimes matches coordinates to different address than another api provided by the `cadastral office`

Comment: The real question is how did you get nested lists into data table? From JSON? Describe the source of data.

Comment: Yes,  i read it in from JSON, which has been generated by a python script used to query Google distance matrix api based on a list of coordinates stored in another Json.

Comment: @Parfait okay, i added a subset of the `json` i am using. That is the source data i am reading into R and then wrangling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one way to think about the problem is to process the list columns using an lapply to expand each separately and store into a list of data.tables and then merge all of those in the list at once.

To create the list of expanded variables you would just do the following:

```
    expandcols<-c("origins","destinations")

    lapply(expandcols,function(i) rbindlist(dt[[i]],idcol = "r")))
```

Also note that your original r column is a character vector and the idcol created by rbindlist is an integer so you will need consistency here. In my code I just converted your original to numeric.

To merge a list of data.tables I like to use the Reduce function like this:

```
     Reduce(function(...) merge(...,by="keys"), list())
```

The output will be one data.table where your key column is "r" and the list will be the result of the lapply call above. You can then merge the result with your original dataframe the data.table way. Putting it altogether the call would look like this:

```
    dtfinal<-Reduce(function(...) merge(...,by="r"),lapply(expandcols,function(i) rbindlist(dt[[i]],idcol = "r")))[dt[,-expandcols,with=F],on="r"]
```

Here is the code for the function I made:

```
    list_expander_fn<-function(X){
      '%notin%'<-Negate('%in%')##Helpful for selecting column names later
      expandcols_fun<-function(Y){##Main function to be called recursively as needed and takes in a data.table object as its only argument.
        listcols<-colnames(Y)[which(sapply(Y,is.list))] #Identify list columns
        listdt<-lapply(listcols,function(i) tryCatch(rbindlist(Y[[i]],idcol = "r"),error=function(e) NULL)) #Expand lists using rbindlist and returns null on error.

        invalidlists<-which(sapply(listdt,is.null)) #Rbindlist does not work unless list elements contain data.tables

##Simply unlists if character vector is created like in destination and origin addresses columns
        if(length(invalidlists)!=0){
            Y[,listcols[invalidlists]:=lapply(.SD,unlist),.SDcols = listcols[invalidlists]]

            listcols<-listcols[-invalidlists] ##Update list columns to be merged
            listdt<-listdt[-invalidlists]##Removes NULL elements from the listdt.
        }

        origcols<-colnames(Y)[colnames(Y)%notin%listcols]##Identifies  nonlist columns for final merge
        currentdt<-Reduce(function(...) merge(...,by="r"),listdt) ##merges list of data.tables
        return(currentdt[Y[,origcols,with=F],on="r"])
        }

      repeat{
        currentexpand<-expandcols_fun(X) #Executes the expandcols_fun
        listcheck<-sapply(currentexpand,is.list) #Checks again if lists still exist
        if(sum(listcheck)!=0){
          X<-currentexpand #Updates the X for recursive calls

        } else{
          break
        }
      }

      return(currentexpand)
}
```

It works but there are issues with variable names because of the final field names (text and value). I could probably tinker with that a bit if you like where this is going. It works on 'rows2' but not 'rows'. The code to call it will be of course simple:

```
    finaldt<-list_expander_fn(dt)
```

Does that help answer your question? Let me know if you want me to add anything to the explanation. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is certainly an improvement. Do you know also how to expand the `rows` column?

Comment: Yes I am working on that too with the basic idea of applying that above code recursively until there are no more list columns in the data.table. Not sure how to do it without writing a function but I will post what I have here shortly which may work or at least generate some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than wrangling in a `data.table`, consider building a data table from the json data object which often imports as a heavily nested list of data frames or other lists. As a result, you need to migrate according to paths of the different level items:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)

json_data <- read_json('/path/to/posted.json')

df_list <- lapply(json_data, function(item)
  data.frame(origin_address = unlist(item$origin_addresses),           # TOP LEVEL
             destination_address = unlist(item$destination_addresses), # TOP LEVEL
             do.call(rbind, lapply(item$origins, data.frame)),         # NESTED LEVEL
             do.call(rbind, lapply(item$destinations, data.frame)))    # NESTED LEVEL
)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)  # SINGLE DATA FRAME
final_dt <- rbindlist(df_list)       # SINGLE DATA TABLE
```

**Output** *(be sure to rename full_address and local_id fields as origin_ or destination_)*

```
final_dt

#                                      origin_address                               destination_address  orig_lon  orig_lat    local_id
# 1: U Jankovky 455/18, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia     Zderazská 98/3, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia  14.36784 49.985982 AD.22045279
# 2:   Otínská 1102/37, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia                Západní 458, 253 01 Chýně, Czechia 14.352792 49.983317 AD.22055428
# 3: U Jankovky 455/18, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia      Zítkova 235/7, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia  14.36784 49.985982 AD.22045279
# 4:   Otínská 1102/37, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia Strážovská 1053/33, 153 00 Praha-Radotín, Czechia 14.352792 49.983317 AD.22055428
#                               full_address  dest_lon  dest_lat  local_id.1                             full_address.1
# 1:  Věštínská 36/9, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5 14.352245 49.981314 AD.22045848     Zderazská 98/3, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5
# 2: Otínská 1102/37, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5 14.226975 50.051702 AD.27261433                   Západní 458, 25303 Chýně
# 3:  Věštínská 36/9, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5  14.36053 49.981687 AD.22047131      Zítkova 235/7, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5
# 4: Otínská 1102/37, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5 14.361052 49.988529 AD.22054952 Strážovská 1053/33, Radotín, 15300 Praha 5
```