# Data Table Containing a List after Aggregate R

Tags: r, list, data.table, crosstab

This might be solved one of two ways. I think I am using the aggregate() function incorrectly - although the results are close to what I want.

I am using:

```
WS_PART = aggregate(PART_WS_Pct$niin_id~PART_WS_Pct$ws_category,  PART_WS_Pct, FUN=function(x) unique(x))
```

The results is almost what I desire, in a way. It contains a main category and then a list of all the parts under that category. Only, the second column of the data is an actual list.

I basically want to make a list for each ws_category containing all the parts.

Right now the data looks like this:

```
MY_CAT1, c("000245290", "000763050", "001218656", "001506526")
MY_CAT2, c("2343","2366")
```

I only have a few categories so I was thinking this could be good as a cross tab. The categories as headers and the PART #'s as rows with each column containing some kind of indicator like TRUE/FALSE or 0/1.

I'm open to more suggestions but those are the two I can think of. Worse case, I can convert the list to characters and do some manipulations that way?

Any advice?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with an expected output.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Unlist data frame column preserving information from other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194298/unlist-data-frame-column-preserving-information-from-other-column).

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and fix your question

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

I think what's happening is that there are variations in the number of parts within each `ws_category`. To remedy this, you'll have to transform your data from one row for each `ws_cartegory`, to one row for each `ws_category` **and** their corresponding parts.

To do this, humor me with a baseball reference. Lots of great players never play for teams that win a World Series while some seem to find themselves earning multiple rings over their caeers.

Here, `df` contains three rows, one for [Ron Santo](https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/s/santoro01.shtml), [Henry Blanco](https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/b/blanche01.shtml), and [John Lester](https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/l/lestejo01.shtml). Both Santo and Blanco never played for a team that won the World Series; however, Lester was part of two championship teams.

To expand `df` so that it has one row per baseball player **and** their corresponding World Series championship year(s), two solutions come to mind:

1. [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse): Use [`tidyr::unnest()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.1/topics/unnest); or
2. Use both the [`base`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/base-package.html) and [`utils`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.0) packages to [`stack()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.0/topics/stack) the unlisted objects within the World Series column.

## Code

```
# load necessary packages
library( tidyverse )

# make data
df <-
  data.frame( Name = c("Ron Santo", "Henry Blanco", "John Lester") )

# add WS Championship Years
df$WS_Champion <-
  list( NA, NA, c(2013, 2016) )

# view results
df
#           Name WS_Champion
# 1    Ron Santo          NA
# 2 Henry Blanco          NA
# 3  John Lester  2013, 2016

# base R solution

# name the objects within the list column
# with their corresponding `Name` value
names( df$WS_Champion ) <- df$Name

# unlist each object within the list column
# and stack the vectors into a data frame
df.stacked <-
  utils::stack( x = lapply( X = df$WS_Champion, FUN = unlist ) )

# rename the columns
colnames( df.stacked ) <- c("WS_Champion", "Name")

# view results
df.stacked
#   WS_Champion         Name
# 1          NA    Ron Santo
# 2          NA Henry Blanco
# 3        2013  John Lester
# 4        2016  John Lester

# tidyverse solution

# unnest df so that 'Name' repeats for every value in 'WS_Champion'
df <-
  unnest( data = df )

# view results
df
#           Name WS_Champion
# 1    Ron Santo          NA
# 2 Henry Blanco          NA
# 3  John Lester        2013
# 4  John Lester        2016

# end of script #
```

## Session Info

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.0   dplyr_0.7.4     purrr_0.2.4    
[5] readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.8.0     tibble_1.4.2    ggplot2_2.2.1  
[9] tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16     cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.2.1    
 [4] compiler_3.4.4   plyr_1.8.4       bindr_0.1.1     
 [7] tools_3.4.4      lubridate_1.7.3  jsonlite_1.5    
[10] nlme_3.1-131.1   gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35 
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.2.0      psych_1.7.8     
[16] cli_1.0.0        rstudioapi_0.7   yaml_2.1.18     
[19] parallel_3.4.4   haven_1.1.1      bindrcpp_0.2    
[22] xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.3.1       hms_0.4.2       
[25] grid_3.4.4       glue_1.2.0       R6_2.2.2        
[28] readxl_1.0.0     foreign_0.8-69   modelr_0.1.1    
[31] reshape2_1.4.3   magrittr_1.5     scales_0.5.0    
[34] rvest_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.0 mnormt_1.5-5    
[37] colorspace_1.3-2 stringi_1.1.7    lazyeval_0.2.1  
[40] munsell_0.4.3    broom_0.4.3      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution, unfortunately, I can't get tidyverse to install. Could be due to older version of R and RStudio. Any chance of another solution like this without tidyverse?

Comment: @MarkGingrass there usually is a `base` R solution! See my updated answer.